# Does CentOS RPM packaging support or dependency in Requires field?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, packaging, rpmbuild

I'd like to know if CentOS supports any **or** package dependencies or Virtual Provides. On Ubuntu, its easy to add an **or** dependency into the Depends field, but can this be done in CentOS?

Ubuntu Or Dependency:

```
TestPackage
Depends: packageA | packageB
```

Ubuntu also can use Virtual Provides:

```
packageA 
Provides: packageAB

packageB
Provides: packageAB

TestPackage
Requires: packageAB
```

Could both of these be used on CentOS?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK `rpm` does **not** support an **or** in dependencies. It does support **virtual packages**. In the spec files this would look exactly like you presented it:

packageA.spec:

```
Provides: packageAB
```

packageB.spec:

```
Provides: packageAB
```

TestPackage.spec:

```
Requires: packageAB
```